# Text-to-speech in GoldenDict

Tags: dictionary, text-to-speech

I know [how to add text-to-speech feature to GoldenDict in Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458584/how-can-i-add-text-to-speech-to-goldendict), but I searched everywhere for a solution for Windows, and found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same solution should work in Windows, but you need something equivalent to `espeak`.

Here is a PowerShell snippet that, using .NET classes, reads some text:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.speech
$speak = New-Object System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
$speak.Speak('Hello.')
```

Here is the equivalent command that can be run in Windows Command Prompt (cmd.exe):

```
PowerShell -Command "Add-Type –AssemblyName System.Speech; (New-Object System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer).Speak('hello');"
```

Using the above command (and replacing 'hello' with '%GDWORD%'), and steps mentioned in [post above](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458584/how-can-i-add-text-to-speech-to-goldendict), we can achieve the same thing.

Here are the full steps:

1. Open GoldenDict and press <kbd>F3</kbd> to bring up the **Dictionaries** window.
2. On the **Sources** tab, select **Programs** tab.
3. Click the **Add** button, select **Audio** for the *Type* column, enter some name ("tts" for example) in the *Name* column, and the following command for the *Command Line* column:

   ```
   PowerShell -Command "Add-Type –AssemblyName System.Speech; (New-Object System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer).Speak('%GDWORD%');"
   ```
4. Don't forget to check the *Enabled* box.
5. Click OK

This uses the default voice in Windows. If you want to use a female voice, use the following command instead:

```
PowerShell -Command "Add-Type –AssemblyName System.Speech; $s=(New-Object System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer); $s.SelectVoiceByHints(2); $s.Speak('%GDWORD%');"
```

Configuring the voice is easy, if you are a .NET programmer and know PowerShell.